# After upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 scanner do not work

Tags: usb, scanner, epson

I have a Epson L382 printer/scanner machine and i use the software available from Epson. The scanner software do not find the scanner - after the upgrade. 
**sane-find-scanner** write this:
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x1120 [L382 Series]) at libusb:002:004
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
**scanimage -L** write this:
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
Any solution?

Comment: Do you have [iscan installed](https://alicious.com/iscan-linux-networked-epson/)?

Answer (score 0):

problems with permissions can normally be gotten around by using  *sudo* .

Try this:

```
 sudo sane-find-scanner
```

Be sure your scanner is on and plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

The group of USB printer device is now `lp`.

It is necessary for the user to be in group `lp`.

You can use de command:

```
sudo adduser <username> lp
```

If you are in X session you need to logout and login again.

Confirm you have the `lp` group with the command `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on HP hardware and using HPLIP, but I had the same issue. The USB device is set up as owned by `root:lp`, so you need to add `saned` to the `lp` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lp saned
```